# logic 9 - max number of tracks 

Tags: logic

hi,

i'm working on a project that demands loads of tracks... for the first time i've reached the max number of tracks Logic can apparently handle - 255 - it won't let me add more tracks, which i need. my question might be stupid but - is the only way for me to continue working is to bounce the current mix and import it into a new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not the only way, but it's a valid way to go.  Bounce down a few tracks based on scenes and start a new project, then import the video and the new tracks -- it will suck for mixing, but you won't lose the old project.

Another solution is to break your current project apart by scene -- it won't require bouncing down, and it will free up any other tracks that are being used by another scene.

If your computer can handle it (and after 255 tracks, I can understand why it might not), consider ReWire options -- I've used both Ableton Live and Cockos Reaper in slave mode with varying levels of success.  Some programs, like Sonar, will require at least a stereo track for the i/o from the ReWire slave, which might mean cleaning up a couple tracks from your 255, but then it opens up a lot more.

As for Logic-specific solutions... I'm a PC guy, so, I don't have any. Sorry.